# why textbf doesn't work when writing between dollar signs between the curly brackets?

Tags: bold

I'm  trying to write the following but in bold: **$M_s$** so that the "s" becomes next to "M" but low and i have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Fundamentals of informatics A4}
\author{some name}
\date{January 2018}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
% some text

into a new Turing machine \textbf{$M_s$} with the following behavior:

%some more text

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the M_s wouldn't appear bold no matter what i try

edit1: \textbf{} works perfectly with just text but when using the dollar signs, it doesn't.

Comment: Well, `\textbf` is meant for text mode, not for content in math mode. You can try `{\boldmath $M_s$}`

Comment: Use `$\mathbf{M_s}$` for upright M or `\boldmath $M_s$\unboldmath`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `bm` package and type `$\bm{M_s}$` to get what you want. The command `\textbf` is for ordinary text, not for mathematical text.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a command that automatically bolds text *and* math:

```
\newcommand{\textmathbf}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath#1}}
```

However, your question seems like you just want to have the `s` as an index to `M` and don't necessarily want them in math mode, so you might want to use:

```
\textbf{$\text{M}_\text{s}$} %% requires \usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in text mode, use `\textbf{}`.
If it's in math mode, use `\mathbf{}`.

Here's the distinction:

```
into a \textbf{new} Turing machine $\mathbf{M_s}$ with the following behavior:
```